# jquery each() returns all objects as the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Disclaimer, i am a rookie developer but am learning as i go. I have been working on this one issue for a few days now trying to interpret similar problems but to no avail.

The problem.  I generate a list dynamically and each `<li>` has 4 input fields, 1 select box, and 2 check boxes.  Values for each input are populated and the users should be able to modify.  On save i am trying to use jquery to loop through the list using each() and return the values so i can push into and array/object ending up with an object for each row with name->value pairs so i can pass with ajax and save the updated input fields.

Here is the code that creates the list.  (be gentle with the rookie)

```
echo'<li id= '.$list[id].' name="clubli" class="club">
<input type="text" name="displayorder" class="clubelement" style=" width:30px; text-align: center;" value="'.$list[display_order].'"; autofocus />
<input type="text" name="clubname" class="clubelement" value="'.$list[club_name].'" /><select id ="clubtype" name="clubtype" class="clubelement" style="width:130px;">
<option selected ="selected">'.$list[club_type].'</option>
  <option id = "'.$results1[0]->id.'">'.$results1[0]->club_type.'</option>
  <option id = "'.$results1[1]->id.'">'.$results1[1]->club_type.'</option>
  <option id = "'.$results1[2]->id.'">'.$results1[2]->club_type.'</option>
  <option id = "'.$results1[3]->id.'">'.$results1[3]->club_type.'</option>
  <option id = "'.$results1[4]->id.'">'.$results1[4]->club_type.'</option>
  <option id = "'.$results1[5]->id.'">'.$results1[5]->club_type.'</option>
</select>
<input style="text-align: center; width: 40px"; type="text" name="clubdist" class="clubelement" value= "'.$list[range_distance].'" /></option>
<input type="checkbox"; name="inactive"; class="clubelement"; '.$active.' /><input type=checkbox name="remove" class="clubelement"; />
<div style="margin-bottom:1em"></div></li>';
```

When user selects save button a JS is called which is as follows:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ jquery/1.12.0  /jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
function saveClubs() {
  $userclubs = [];
    $('.clubslist li').each(function(i) {
      $id=$("[name='clubli']").attr('id');
      $displayorder= $("[name='displayorder']").val();
      $clubname= $("[name='clubname']").val();
      $clubtype= $("[name='clubtype']").val();
      $clubdist= $("[name='clubdist']").val();
      $clubinactive= $("[name='inactive']").is(":checked");
      $clubremove= $("[name='remove']").is(":checked");
  $userclubs.push({'id':$id, 'displayorder':$displayorder, 'clubname':$clubname, 'clubtype':$clubtype, 'clubdist':$clubdist, 'inactive':$clubinactive, 'remove':$clubremove});
 });
```

console.log($userclubs);

The console log show a result of "object" "object" "object" "object" which is expected as there are 4 rows to the list.  However each object as the same 7 inputs in them - all the first row of the list.  I understand that the loop is reading the first row everytime even though it is loops the expected number of times.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: You're using selectors inside your `each()` loop, so its selecting just the first match.  You want to use `$(this)`.

Comment: Ah yes, i did read that each() picks the first match so it's just looping on the first list element....thanks for the tip.  i can pursue that.

Comment: Not exactly..... `each()` *is* looping over all the `li` elements, but the query selectors *inside* the loop are only getting data from the first element they match.  I made this example to help illustrate:  https://jsfiddle.net/4sL0fmz9/  Give it a run and take a look at the console.

Comment: yes, looked at the fiddle, and then implemented your suggestion and it worked first time in my code.....genius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, they query selectors (e.g. `$displayorder= $("[name='displayorder']").val();`) are going to match the first value.  So for each iteration of the loop, you only get the first matched DOM element.

To fix that, you'd need to reference the DOM element that the `each()` loop is currently iterating over.  Something like this would work:

```
function saveClubs() {
  $userclubs = [];
    $('.clubslist li').each(function(i) {
      $id=$(this).attr('id');
      $displayorder= $(this).find("[name='displayorder']").val();
      $clubname= $(this).find("[name='clubname']").val();
      $clubtype= $(this).find("[name='clubtype']").val();
      $clubdist= $(this).find("[name='clubdist']").val();
      $clubinactive= $(this).find("[name='inactive']").is(":checked");
      $clubremove= $(this).find("[name='remove']").is(":checked");
  $userclubs.push({'id':$id, 'displayorder':$displayorder, 'clubname':$clubname, 'clubtype':$clubtype, 'clubdist':$clubdist, 'inactive':$clubinactive, 'remove':$clubremove});
 });
 }
```

Here is an example in a JS Fiddle, where you can see it working with some test data based on your PHP:  https://jsfiddle.net/qg063zaL/

Hope that helps! :-)

Comment: you solved my problem in 7 minutes after hours of struggle.  This rookie cannot thank you enough.